# How to handle occasional SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server?

Tags: java, rest, cxf

I have a REST service that calls another remote service.

Most of the time the communication works fine, but occasionally, I encounter

```
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientWebApplicationException: 
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
SocketException invoking https://url: Unexpected end of file from server
```

I did some research and found it's the remote server shut down the connection unexpectedly.

It really puzzles me, because everything (input, header, etc) is the same and I was testing with a small amount of requests only like (50-100), I have tried both in sequence and in parallel, only a few will encounter this issue.

Why would this happen? Do I have to ask the remote server to reconfigure, or do I have to implement a retry pattern in my service in this case?

Any hint?

Thanks

P.S

I am using

```
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient
```

to invoke the remote service. Will it make any difference if I switch to HttpClient?

Comment: I want to add a comment to my own problem. It seems that the remote server is setup to reject the connection when multiple are already established. to resolve it, I simply disabled the Keep-Alive, and it seems to be working. but I am not sure if it is the best solution, as it might invoke the SSL handkshake for every request and impact the performance